# PYQGIS Composer Label Alignment

Tags: alignment, label, pyqt4, qgis, atlas

I've been working on a bit of script for QGIS in order to automate atlas generation through the composer.

The only issue I've had is I can't align the composer label correctly. Here's the code sample:

```
composerLabel = QgsComposerLabel(c)
newFont = QFont("times", 40)
composerLabel.setFont(newFont) 
composerLabel.setText("Hello world")
composerLabel.adjustSizeToText()
composerLabel.setItemPosition(c.paperWidth() / 2,0)

composerLabel.setHAlign(Qt.AlignCenter)

c.addItem(composerLabel)
```

[Here's what the image output looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xHDb.jpg)

I've had a look at the API and scowered PYQGIS forums but no-one else sounds like they're having similar alignment issues. Can anyone see where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need add the **ItemPositionMode** in the `setItemPosition` method.

```
# add label
composerLabel = QgsComposerLabel(c)
newFont = QFont("times", 40)
composerLabel.setFont(newFont) 
composerLabel.setText("Hello world")
composerLabel.adjustSizeToText()
composerLabel.setItemPosition(c.paperWidth() / 2,0,QgsComposerItem.UpperMiddle)

composerLabel.setHAlign(Qt.AlignCenter)

c.addComposerLabel(composerLabel)
```

Comment: Fantastic! Yep, that sorted out the issue. Thanks Francisco! =)